# svn move and local changes

Tags: svn, move, collaboration

I need to do svn move to rearrange folders in my repo. What happen if I do the svn move while other team members have uncommited changes in their local copy? Will they lose those local changes?

Thank you very much

Comment: As many people already told you, try to mark as accepted the answers that helped you solve your problem. You asked 6 questions and not a single one of them has an accepted answer. If you keep doing this, people will begin ignoring your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When they commit, they will be forced to update first. Then they will update, will get a conflict, and will have to resolve it manually.

Answer (score 0):

No, they won't. But trust me, it will be a nightmare if you don't pay attention, Subversion's not at all smart in such situations.

If at all possible, make them commit every change, update your working copy and *only then* can you start shuffling stuff around without causing much grief.

Do anything else and you're screwed.

I'm assuming you don't have branches, because if you do, the next merge will be painful.